# How to allign components to the background in Netbeans GUI Builder?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I know Java but not perfect and I am new to the GUI world. I am trying to design a program with lots of buttons, combo boxes and text fields placed in rows. I can't get components evenly spread out in the row. It is hard to be precise with the mouse. I hope this is not a silly question. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use an IDE to create the GUI. Build your GUI's by writing the code yourself. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for example code. Don't forget you can use nested panels with different layout managers. In other words spend time learning Java, not the IDE.

Comment: Yea I was thinking of learning it but the tutorial recommended using Netbeans IDE.